# Symfony EventListener: why protected (and not private) members?

Tags: symfony, scope, event-listener

So I was just wondering why every EventListener examples I see on the internet uses members with *protected* scope instead of *private*.

I personnaly would use private members , as

1. I'm unlikely to extend one of my EventListener
2. I kinda learned that it was " the norm " to write classes using *private* members, thus making *protected* ones the exceptions.

So did I miss a memo about the scope of class members, or is there a reason why everybody seems to use class-protected members in Sf Listeners?

Thanks

Comment: Choosing scope is totally up to you.

Comment: I think a big part of it is that you were probably looking at code that was meant to be extended.  Most of the core stuff and many of more popular add ins setup their services such that all you need to do is set a parameter to a new class name in order to extend and tweak the service.  At which point having protected variables is nice.

Comment: I completely agree with you on using private members instead of protected when you are sure that you'll not be extending your class.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with you on using private members instead of protected when you are sure that you'll not be extending your class.

Comment: -1 Sorry for downvote, but this answer does not meet StackOverflow's standard and should be posted as a comment to the original question.